# Controlling layout of phantom-html2pdf document

Tags: html, css, node.js, pdf-conversion

I'm using [phantom-html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom-html2pdf) to generate pdfs dynamically in a Node app. The conversion works but the layout is completely off. For example the html document is a form that consists of sections sometimes with two columns side-by-side.

I am using [MUI](https://www.muicss.com/) css for some styling and layout which has been in-lined into the HTML before the PDF conversion.  After the PDF conversion everything is in one column, despite the fact that I have divs with `class="mui-col-md-6"` which render fine in the browser.

I've tried adding custom CSS and adding `pageSize` values but no matter what I do it's not producing the result I'm after.

Here is what I have in options at the moment. Note I've passed through some css where I try to "reshape" the document to make it more like the original HTML but it seems to have limited effect on the final layout. Also I set a negative border which helps a bit but doesn't remove PDF border completely as I'd like.

```
 var pdfOptions = {
    html: html, // html with in-lined MUI styles - columns not rendering
    css: pdfCss, // This CSS seems to have has limited control over final layout
    paperSize: {format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '-2cm'}
  }
```

If anyone has any advice on how to get more control over the layout to make it look more like my HTML I'd be very grateful. Cheers!

**UPDATE**

It appears that phantom-html2pdf ignores any inline css and only applies css passed in as part of the options. Again, I'm open to any pointers so correct me if I'm wrong or missing some steps to have more control over the final layout.